# How to make navitem active even after clicking somewhere else on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nav

I am sort of new to javascript and having trouble with my code. Can anyone help me figure out the issue. Currently the navitem is in focused state and highlighted menu gets removed when clicked somewhere else. (it stays highlighted/active if nothing is clicked on the page). I want it to be highlighted even if I click somewhere else on the same page.

```
const LinkItems: Array<LinkItemProps> = [
    { name: "Home", icon: FiHome,href:"/" },
    { name: "About", icon: FiCalendar,href:"/About" },
    { name: "Contact", icon: FiPenTool ,href:"/Contact"},
];

export default function Sidebar() {
    const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
    const { data: session, status } = useSession();

    if (session) {
        return (
      <Box>
        <SidebarContent
          onClose={() => onClose}
          display={{ base: "none", xl: "block" }}
        />
        <Drawer
          autoFocus={false}
          isOpen={isOpen}
          placement="left"
          onClose={onClose}
          returnFocusOnClose={false}
          onOverlayClick={onClose}
          size="xs"
        >
          <DrawerContent           
             bg={bgColor}
            bgGradient={bgGradientColor}
            height="450px"
            color={color}
            borderRightRadius="2xl"
            boxShadow={boxShadowColor}
            fontSize="14px"
          >
            <SidebarContent onClose={onClose} />
          </DrawerContent>
        </Drawer>       
      </Box>
        );
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

interface SidebarProps extends BoxProps {
  onClose: () => void;
}

const SidebarContent = ({ onClose, ...rest }: SidebarProps) => {
  return (
    <Box
      as="nav"
      id="nav"
      w={{ base: "auto", xl: "180px" }}
      pos="relative"
      h="auto"
      mt="2.5"
      {...rest}
    >
      <Flex alignItems="center" mx="2" justifyContent="flex-end">
        <CloseButton display={{ base: "flex", xl: "none" }} onClick={onClose} role="button" />
      </Flex>
      {LinkItems.map((link) => (
        <NavItem key={link.name} style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}  _focus={{ boxShadow: "none" }} icon={link.icon} href={link.href} onClick={onClose} role="link">
          {link.name}
        </NavItem>
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
};
```

I have tried to modify the CSS like below but it didn't work.

```
nav a:focus,
nav a:active {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)!important;
    outline: 0;
}
.chakra-ui-dark nav a:focus,
.chakra-ui-dark nav a:active {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.15)!important;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider having a class on the active element, and using this class in your current rules, like:

```css
nav a:focus,
nav a:active,
nav a.active {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)!important;
  outline: 0;
}
.chakra-ui-dark nav a:focus,
.chakra-ui-dark nav a:active,
.chakra-ui-dark nav a.active {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.15)!important;
  outline: 0;
}
```

Have a state that keeps track of the item that should be active:

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(null);
```

Update the `active` variable with a clicked link's `href` value:

```
const onClick = (link) => (...args) => {
  onClose(...args);
  setActive(link.href);
};

<NavItem … onClick={onClick(link)}>
```

Toggle the `active` class on the element when the `active` variable string matches the `link.href` (assuming `className` would render classes onto the `<a>` element within the `<NavItem>` component):

```
className={active === link.href ? 'active' : ''}
```

All of it together in `SidebarContent` as follows:

```
const SidebarContent = ({ onClose, ...rest }: SidebarProps) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(null);
  const onClick = (link) => (...args) => {
    onClose(...args);
    setActive(link.href);
  };

  return (
    <Box
      as="nav"
      id="nav"
      w={{ base: "auto", xl: "180px" }}
      pos="relative"
      h="auto"
      mt="2.5"
      {...rest}
    >
      <Flex alignItems="center" mx="2" justifyContent="flex-end">
        <CloseButton display={{ base: "flex", xl: "none" }} onClick={onClose} role="button" />
      </Flex>
      {LinkItems.map((link) => (
        <NavItem key={link.name} style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}  _focus={{ boxShadow: "none" }} icon={link.icon} href={link.href} onClick={onClick(link)} role="link" className={active === link.href ? 'active' : ''}>
          {link.name}
        </NavItem>
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Comment: That code partially worked. Now, if I click on a button that redirects to a different page for example: if I click on the "about" button from homepage, in that case, the about page is not highlighted in the sidebar. any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: You'll want to have some parameter that marks the page and sets the default state accordingly, such as in server-side code or you could match via `window.location`.

Comment: I tried using window.location. but the home navbar kept active. below is the code I've tried:

SidebarProps extends BoxProps {
  onClose: () => void;
}

const SidebarContent = ({ onClose, ...rest }: SidebarProps) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setActive(window.location.pathname);
  }, []);

  const onClick = (link) => (...args) => {
    onClose.apply(null, args);
    setActive(link.href);
  };